# Redirects work in cUrl, but often not in browser - how to debug this?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, browser

I have a list with 301 redirects, like `Redirect 301 path/to/url/1 path/of/url/2` or `Redirect 301 /url3 /url4`. The list is placed in htaccess.

If I test redirects in Chrome and FF (usual and incognito), I get multiple 404 errors, like some redirects wouldn't be properly working. If I test redirects with `cUrl` - all redirects are working properly.

What happens with browsers in this context? Why I can't see a reliable state of redirects?

My main problem with this: how can I be sure, redirects are working for my site's visitors? They surf with Chrome, not with cUrl...

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: tried everything: clean cache, cookies, restart, incognito window - no luck.